# Find machine with specific software only if another software does NOT exist

Tags: powershell

I've been tasked with creating a report where I need to find machines that just have Office 365 ProPlus and not OneDrive.  We have a mixed environment where, for business purposes, some machines have both and others only have O365.  I need a list of all machines that have O365 (weeding out the O365\OneDrive combo machines).

This is where I am currently:

```
$OutPath = "c:\Machines_with_O365.csv"
$Software = "Microsoft Office 365 ProPlus*"

$Computers = Get-ADComputer -Filter *
foreach ($Computer in $Computers) {
    $Ping = Test-Connection -ComputerName $Computer.Name -Quiet -Count 1 
    if ($Ping -eq $true) {
        try {
            $MachineName = $Computer.Name 
            Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product -ComputerName $computer.Name -ErrorAction Stop |
                ? {$_.Name -like $Software} |
                Select-Object @{N="ComputerName";E={$Computer.Name}}, Vendor, Name |
                Export-Csv $OutPath -Append
        } catch {
            Write-Host "Unable to Obtain WMI Object of $MachineName" 
        }
    }
}
if ($Ping -eq $false) {
    Write-Host "The $MachineName is not pingable" 
}
```

What do I need to add\change to get me to the finish line?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the list of installed software contains one program, but doesn't contain the other. Try something like this:

```
$MachineName = $Computer.Name 
$softwarList = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product -Computer $MachineName -ErrorAction Stop
if ($softwareList -contains $Software -and $softwareList -notcontains $OneDrive) {
    $softwareList |
        Select-Object @{n='ComputerName';e={$MachineName}}, Vendor, Name |
        Export-Csv $OutPath -Append
```

Be warned though, that the `Win32_Product` class is [considered harmful](https://gregramsey.net/2012/02/20/win32_product-is-evil/), because queries to that class might trigger a package reconfiguration.